# Generic Json Map Setter in Java

Tags: java, json, dictionary

Suppose I have an empty Map<String, Object> map or a Map<String, Object> map with some fields added.

In this case, I want to create a generic java method that I can set to the map I have using the values such as map, path, value type and value object that I will give as input.

The method outline I intend to create can be seen below.

```
public void genericJsonMapSet(Map<String, Object> jsonMap, String setPath, String setValueType, Object setValue) {
    //Set JsonMap code
}
```

The json representation of the map before and after the following calls of the method to be created should be as follows.

```
    genericJsonMapSet(jsonMap, "setid()", "string", "a9a9940d-593f-4546-8065-6d70370d9f64");
    genericJsonMapSet(jsonMap, "setrequestDate()", "string", "2022-10-10 16:20:15");
    genericJsonMapSet(jsonMap, "setuserCharacteristic[1].setvalueType()", "string", "string");
    genericJsonMapSet(jsonMap, "setuserCharacteristic[1].setname()", "string", "username");
    genericJsonMapSet(jsonMap, "setuserCharacteristic[1].setvalue()", "string", "taner.turan");
    genericJsonMapSet(jsonMap, "setuserCharacteristic[2].setvalueType()", "string", "integer");
    genericJsonMapSet(jsonMap, "setuserCharacteristic[2].setname()", "string", "id");
    genericJsonMapSet(jsonMap, "setuserCharacteristic[2].setvalue()", "integer", "23");
```

***Before:***

```
{

}
```

***After:***

```
{
    "id": "a9a9940d-593f-4546-8065-6d70370d9f64",
    "requestDate": "2022-10-10 16:20:15",
    "userCharacteristic": [
        {
            "valueType": "string",
            "name": "username",
            "value": "taner.turan"
        },
        {
            "valueType": "integer",
            "name": "id",
            "value": 23
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone provide code for this?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code-writing service. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Stackoverflow will help with _specific_ problems, but will not write code for any assignments that are dumped on it.

Answer (score 0):

[This project](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/com.zwitserloot.json) works similarly. I wrote it.. a long long time ago, as far as I know nobody uses it. `Map<String, Object>` is not java-like at all; there is almost no purpose to such a thing. I encapsulated the notion into a `JSON` object instead. Also, you don't use strings to 'set' things, again, un-java like.  Thus, this code:

> ```
> Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();
> genericJsonMapSet(jsonMap, "setid()", "string", "a9a9940d-593f-4546-8065-6d70370d9f64");
> genericJsonMapSet(jsonMap, "setuserCharacteristic[1].setvalueType()", "string", "string");
> genericJsonMapSet(jsonMap, "setuserCharacteristic[2].setvalue()", "integer", "23");
> ```

Becomes:

```java
JSON j = JSON.newMap();
j.get("setId").setString("a9a9940d-593f-4546-8065-6d70370d9f64");
j.get("setuserCharacteristic").add().setString("string");
j.get("setuserCharacteristic").get(2).setInteger(23);
```

`add()` is the same as `.get(i)` where i is one larger than whatever is there already. You can `get` non-existent things; they are created automatically once you `.set` anywhere in the 'chain'. i.e.:

```java
JSON j = JSON.newMap();
j.get("foo").get("bar").setString("hello");
```

Gives you JSON structure:

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "hello"
  }
}
```

[Link to code on github](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/com.zwitserloot.json)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the function `unflatten()` of library *Josson* to do what you want.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.create();
josson.put("id", "a9a9940d-593f-4546-8065-6d70370d9f64");
josson.put("requestDate", "2022-10-10 16:20:15");
josson.put("userCharacteristic[1].valueType", "string");
josson.put("userCharacteristic[1].name", "username");
josson.put("userCharacteristic[1].value", "taner.turan");
josson.put("userCharacteristic[2].valueType", "integer");
josson.put("userCharacteristic[2].name", "id");
josson.put("userCharacteristic[2].value", 23);
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("unflatten('.[]')");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "id" : "a9a9940d-593f-4546-8065-6d70370d9f64",
  "requestDate" : "2022-10-10 16:20:15",
  "userCharacteristic" : [ {
    "valueType" : "string",
    "name" : "username",
    "value" : "taner.turan"
  }, {
    "valueType" : "integer",
    "name" : "id",
    "value" : 23
  } ]
}
```